# GNU screen: move between regions

Tags: gnu-screen

I've started splitting window in GNU screen into different regions - rather than switching between windows.

Anyway, having split a window into 4 regions (2x2) it takes 3 `C-a <Tab>` to return focus to the original region. That is quite cumbersome...

Are there other keybindings to *move up, down, left, right* between regions?

I can't understand [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Focus): hitting `C-a t` gives me time, does not switch to top win.

Should I change keybindings?

Comment: Adding as a comment since it's not an answer but see if tmux is available for your distribution.  It's a modern re-write of what screen is.  Very nifty and cleanly supports exactly what you're asking for.  http://tmux.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Kyle: thanks, I know of tmux and probably I'll check it out. Moreover I notice `screen` splits are lost if you detach and reattach or just lock. A the end swapping between *full-screen* windows using `C-a C-a` or `C-a` _windownumber_ is way more comfortable...

Answer (score 15):

**screen** commands for switching between regions are: actually `focus up`, `focus down`, `focus right` and `focus left`. To type these commands (or any other **screen** command, for that matter) you type `C-a :focus up`, for example.

These commands are tedious to type, that's why you must create key bindings in your *~/.screenrc* file. Since I'm a **Vim** user I opted for these lines in my *~/.screenrc* file:

```
bind j focus down
bind k focus up
bind l focus right
bind h focus left
```

To switch to the left region I type `C-a h`

Comment: I guess a vim user would have `bind ; focus right` and `bind l focus left`

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the manual (man screen) - search for focus (using <kbd>/</kbd> to search).
There is an example for binding focus up/down/top/bottom keys there.
Not sure about left/right - focus doesn't seem to accept those as parameters.

Comment: you are right about left and right, it was top and bottom, my fault. The link in my answer is same as man screen anyway. It would be useful to me having a `C-a Shift <Tab>` to go backwards in order...

Comment: if I only knew what to put in `bind` command for `Shift` and `Tab`...

Comment: Yes - that would make a load of sense - you could probably bind it to focus up. You may need to figure out a termcap name for shift + tab though. A quick google shows that may take a bit of fiddling.

Comment: Okay - names I've found (none which yet work with/without -k) backtab, shifted-tab, F91, kB.

Comment: This looks useful - http://www.staldal.nu/tech/2009/01/10/how-to-use-ctrl-tab-in-gnu-screen/

Comment: @Danny: thanks for searching, the [link](http://www.staldal.nu/tech/2009/01/10/how-to-use-ctrl-tab-in-gnu-screen/) as far as I understand uses `Xresources` but on my ubuntu server I have no X... is it possible anyway? In the past I used `xev` to get key codes form wm keybindings, nothing that works without X. I read about using cat to show sequence (`^[[Z`) but can't find a way to fit it into screen `bind`

Comment: Interesting - that sequence defaults to copy - ^[. How are you interacting with the box - local vt or via remote shell session?

Comment: @Danny: via remote shell (ssh)

Comment: using xev I get `keysym 0xfe20` (octal 177040) for `Shift Tab` (`ISO_Left_Tab`) but screen bind does not accept \0177040 as octal, too long as it complains waiting for something like \032...