# How to bind 'tab' and 'shift+tab' in GNU screen?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen

How do I bind the keys <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> in screen? My problem is that I don’t know what to pass to the screen `bind` command to designate these keystrokes.

BTW, I’m aware of [GNU screen: move between regions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14142/41470) but the answer is not there.

All of the following fail with the error `-X: bind: character, ^x, or (octal) \032 expected`:

```
screen -X bind "\033[Z" focus up
screen -X bind "^[[Z" focus up
screen -X bind "\t" focus up
screen -X bind \033[Z focus up
screen -X bind ^[[Z focus up
screen -X bind \t focus up
```

Same thing if I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to input the command.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I would agree, except that: 1) other people might find this question useful if they're looking for this particular case; 2) I still couldn't find exactly what to pass to bind to make this work - see (upcoming) edit

Comment: OK, retracting the close vote since it's a newer question now. Unfortunately, the way SE works, unless all the other closers retract their close votes, it's likely to end up being closed...

Comment: Please reopen, that was me closing it by mistake.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: something I should do to reopen?

Comment: Nope. Wait for enough people with enough reputation to vote for reopen, like for the closing.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to `bindkey` where you can specify character sequences, with `bind`, the only way is by using `bind -k CAP` where CAP is a `termcap` key capability.

For instance,

```
bind -k ku focus up
```

works to bind the sequence of character sent upon <kbd>Up</kbd> to `focus up`. For backtab, that should be:

```
bind -k kB focus up
```

Unfortunately, for some reason, it doesn't see to work. Not sure why. My first interpretation was wrong. It sounds like it has something to do with with `ncurses` not handling the termcap equivalent of `kcbt` correctly:

```
$ infocmp -1 | grep Z
    cbt=\E[Z,
    kcbt=\E[Z,
$ infocmp -1C | grep Z
    :bt=\E[Z:\
```

(kcbt is no translated to kB).

If I add to my `~/.screenrc`:

```
 termcapinfo * kr=\E[Z
 bind -k kr focus up
```

That is, if I tell `screen` that whatever the *host* termincal (`*`), <kbd>F63</kbd> (`kr`) sends `\E[Z`, and bind <kbd>F63</kbd> to `focus up`, then that works. However note that pressing <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> now sends *within screen* `\EOC`, which is the character sequence that the terminal emulator that *screen* implements (as opposed to the host terminal) sends upon <kbd>F63</kbd>.

Comment: I didn't quite get this answer and it didn't work for me. bind doesn't have a -k option here (at least not documented). I get also "character, ^x, or (octal) \032 expected" with your bind cmds. But thanks for the help anyway

Comment: OK I figured you probably meant bindkey instead of bind. Tried that and it now `Shift+TAB` does focus up. But not after `Ctrl+A` as with tab, so it is still no symmetric. I basically wanted to have `C-a shit-tab` be the symmetric of the default `C-a tab`

Comment: @ricab, `bind -k` works for me though it's not documented (`4.01.00devel`)

Comment: Interesting, it does not work here (4.00.03 (FAU)). I get the error `bind: character, ^x, or (octal) \032 expected`

Comment: regarding *"(kcbt is no translated to kB)."* -- that's probably because the termcap was trimmed to fit in 1023 bytes (expected behavior).

Answer (score 0):

```
bindkey -k kB stuff ^[OZ
bind -k kB focus up
```

In my case the problem is that the string inserted when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is `^[[Z` after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> which translates in

- `^[` enter copy/scrollback mode
- `[` abort
- and then show `Z`

i.e. the standard VT100 style escape sequence of characters is in conflict whit copy/scrollback mode character sequence. So I added a key binding for the backtab termcap name `kB` to change the string inserted in the input buffer when <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed to `^[OB`.

See the "INPUT TRANSLATION" section in the screen man page.